# How do I create a message queue?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I want to display little messages to provide feedback to the user while he
is providing input or just interacting with the UI.

I need it for my firefox addon, so I have to develop it in plain javascript 
and not jQuery.

I want the message to appear, but only one message can be visible at the same
time, so I need some kind of queue to manage incomming messages. After a certain time 
e.g. 3 sec the message should fade away or just disappear.

For now I am able to add messages to the DOM. Any suggestions how to implement the queue
and how to push the messages forward according to the time?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps not call it `message queue`. [Message queuing](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/message-queues) is terminology reserved for computer science / engineering that describes a different concept. Better call it notification queue. Thanks for updating your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery in a firefox plugin:

Include a script tag in the xul file that points to the jQuery file, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome://extensionname/content/jquery.js" />
```

In each js function that uses jQuery, insert this line:

```
$jQuizzle = jQuery.noConflict();
```

In each jQuery call, if you are trying to manipulate the document in the current browser window, you must supply the context as "window.content.document", like this:

```
$jQuizzle(".myClass", window.content.document).show();
```

Then you can use this jQuery plugin:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-message-queuing-plugin/

Comment: hm this does not work for me, I tried to hide the whole content with $jQuizzle("#smsflatrateSidebar", window.content.document).hide(); but nothing happens

Comment: $jQuizzle = jQuery.noConflict();  seems to fail

Comment: Have you added the jquery file into content and changed the extensionname to what ever you're extension is called?

Comment: Jquery is included sucessfully this way <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://smsflatrate/content/scripts/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/> but calling $jQuizzle = jQuery.noConflict(); 
   $jQuizzle("#myTabList", window.content.document).hide(); in a js file that is included in the same xul file fails

Comment: if I do alert($jQuizzle("#myTabList", window.content.document).html()) it alerts "null"

Answer (score 4):

Perheps you need the concept of **FIFO (First In First Out)**

Take a look at this simple example in plan java script language:

```
function Queue() {
    var data = [];

    this.isEmpty = function() {
        return (data.length == 0);
    };

    this.enqueue = function(obj) {
        data.push(obj);
    };

    this.dequeue = function() {
        return data.shift();
    };

    this.peek = function() {
        return data[0];
    };

    this.clear = function() {
        data = [];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what sort of message you want to display. The [nsIAlertsService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIAlertsService) can display messages but I'm not sure how well it queues them. If you want something simpler then perhaps you could just show a custom `<tooltip>` element.

Comment: this is actually what I came up with :)